# CLIPS - Adding the slots of two facts

Tags: addition, clips

I am fairly new to **CLIPS** , been trying to implement a program , based on a lecture , that adds the values of 2 slots , of two facts respectively. I begin with defining the templates of `o1` , `o2` (the two facts that we add) and `o3` (where we store the result) . Each of the first two facts , `o1` and `o2` , have 2 **slots** , `s1` and `s2` . The slots of `o3` are `r1` and `r2` .  Then I proceed to initialize the slots `o1` and `o2` , using **deffacts** . Then , ending , using **defrule** , I set variables to the slots of `o1` and `o2` and using **assert** to generate the `o3` fact , which slots `r1` will have the sum of values of the first slot of the facts `o1` and `o2` , and `r2` will the sum of the second . I'm using ubuntu , loading the clp clips file with `clips -f try.clp` command , and then executing `(run)` and at last , `(facts)` , but can't see the new facts , or either of the pre-existing ones . Can someone guide me with this ? I'm posting my code and screenshot of running the program.

Here is my code :

```
(deftemplate o1
    (slot s1) 
    (slot s2))

(deftemplate o2
    (slot s1) 
    (slot s2)) 

(deftemplate o3
    (slot r1)
    (slot r2))

; Facts
(deffacts F 
    (o1 (s1 3)(s2 5))
    (o2 (s1 7)(s2 9)))


; Rules
(defrule R 
    (o1 (s1 ?x1)(s2 ?y1))
    (o2 (s1 ?x2)(s2 ?y2))
=>
    (assert (o3(r1 (+ ?x1 ?x2))(r2 (+ ?y1 ?y2))))
)
```

and screenshot with running the program :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to issue a (reset) command before your (run) command. Reset removes all existing facts and then asserts the facts specified in your deffacts.

Comment: yes , thank you , I figured it out some hours ago . Thanks again for replying . I will post later the full answer also .